# boost::asio::system_timer doesn't ignore signals

Tags: c++, boost, timer, c++17, boost-asio

I have a timer code that uses `boost::asio::system_timer` object to perform some actions:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_context timer_context;
boost::asio::signal_set term_signals(timer_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
term_signals.async_wait(exit_signal_handler);
boost::asio::system_timer timer(timer_context);
while(!exit_program) {
    auto expiration_time =
        std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    expiration_time =
        expiration_time - (expiration_time % std::chrono::seconds(30));
    expiration_time += std::chrono::seconds(30);
    auto tp = std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock >(
        std::chrono::duration(expiration_time));
    timer.expires_at(tp);
    timer.wait();
    <do some stuff>
}
```

But when I send `SIGINT` to the program `wait()` intercepts it and throws an `interrupted system call` exception.

Is there any way to make the timer either ignore the signal or have it use a predefined handler instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is no predifined handler to do it. But doing it manually should not be that hard. Instead of calling plain `wait()` do it this in a loop:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_context timer_context;
boost::asio::signal_set term_signals(timer_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
term_signals.async_wait(exit_signal_handler);
boost::asio::system_timer timer(timer_context);
while(!exit_program) {
    auto expiration_time =
        std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    expiration_time =
        expiration_time - (expiration_time % std::chrono::seconds(30));
    expiration_time += std::chrono::seconds(30);
    auto tp = std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock >(
        std::chrono::duration(expiration_time));
    timer.expires_at(tp);
    auto e = boost::system::error_code{};
    do {
        timer.wait(e);
    } while (e == boost::asio::error::interrupted);
    if (e) {
        //<handle non-interrupted error>
    }
    //<do some stuff>
}
```